# TypeScript union check for existence of object key

Tags: typescript

I have a function that accepts a payload, and part of that payload is a `data` property that could be an array of objects, or an object with specific properties. Based on whether or not some key is provided on the payload, in this example `propA`, I want to return the value of that key, or a default value of 150. I created a union type for the data property, seen here on the `FunctionInterface` example.

The problem is this results in a TS error `...Property 'propA' does not exist on type 'Record<string, unknown>[]'.`

How might I update my function interface, or function body, to work with something like this?

```
interface FunctionInterface {
    data: Record<string, unknown>[] | { propA: number, propB?: string[] }
}

function myFunction(payload: FunctionInterface) {
    return payload.data.propA || 150;
}

const result1 = myFunction({ data: { propA: 4 } }); // expect 4
const result2 = myFunction({ data: [{ 'a': 1, 'b': 2 }, { 'a': 3, 'b': 4 }] }); // expect 150
```

[TS Playground example](http://interface%20FunctionInterface%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20data:%20Record%3Cstring,%20unknown%3E%5B%5D%20%7C%20%7B%20propA:%20number,%20propB?:%20string%5B%5D%20%7D%20%7D%20%20function%20myFunction(payload:%20FunctionInterface)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20return%20payload.data.propA%20%7C%7C%20150;%20%7D%20%20const%20result1%20=%20myFunction(%7B%20data:%20%7B%20propA:%204%20%7D%20%7D);%20//%20expect%204%20const%20result2%20=%20myFunction(%7B%20data:%20%5B%7B%20%27a%27:%201,%20%27b%27:%202%20%7D,%20%7B%20%27a%27:%203,%20%27b%27:%204%20%7D%5D%20%7D);%20//%20expect%20150)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript is complaining because it doesn't allow access to properties that may not exist.

The `data` prop property here is either an array, or an object, so you need to handle both cases.

The easiest way to do this is probably to check if `.data` is an array, then return the default, else return the property.

```
function myFunction(payload: FunctionInterface) {
    return Array.isArray(payload.data) ? 150 : payload.data.propA
}
```

This works because once you test if data is an array, then typescript remembers that and knows that if that check failed, then the value must be the only other member of the union.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIFcQLMA9iASXGniWQG8BYAKGTuQBM4w4AuZAJQgVygYB4AzmCigA5gBpkmANYhcAdxAA+ANoBdZAB8KyAA5RcegILsQ6ALYAjaFINGAQgH52w0SDEbkAXxq-qNDCY2HggyBYAnhhYOPgAFHpwEQA2uHAM7NEh+ESQsIgQAJQUNPTIUBBg6FBhxlBQSQB0wIJ1DREJSanpjUwsxU7IAIwArAAMyOyJKWkMvcxwjfYmfjQ0PCDC5RCC6MlgQ8gAvOFRwbEgceSMC+zXy6bIACw+PoUA3MgA9F-IEAAeem4YGe63wWwqu32ACZjqcshcrjcWOxVNcAORwdHsIZSdFWbHIWHeKQYrHsADMeIJ7Be3k03g+31+AKB2GG4zW1A2glwyQgjVSYjikL2B2KP1B3PBfIFQpFOzF0Ilv1GYxoQA)